# R how to read txt file with variable length last column

Tags: r

I try to use this syntax but problem thta my txt file has diff length for last column I'm interested in, how to select it with width= from pos.12 till end of line?  is there such way ?   I put samples line from my file below, Tx all
Mario

`01/08/2015 New Features.mp4 
 01/08/2015 Add percent total.mp4
 01/08/2015 Fix length.mp4`

`read.fwf("data.txt", c(11,????)`

Comment: You need to provide more info.  Is the separation between `2015` and the title a space or a tab?  Do you require merging all the text prior to `xxx.mp4` ? and so on.   If every white space is a space, I'd recommend using any text editor to replace "2015" with "2015\t" (tab character) and using `read.table` with the separator set to a tab

Comment: if those are the only two columns, you could just use `c(11, 50)` or something

Comment: You can use a slightly higher value in case there are some lines with more characters `read.fwf('data11.txt', widths=c(11, 1e4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)$V2
#[1] "New Features.mp4"      "Add percent total.mp4" "Fix length.mp4" `

Comment: Yes, I could have spaces inside of each column,  I could have or NOT have tabs or other separeted values, that's why I'concentrate on fixed length concept.

Comment: akrun, and rawr, it's easy!!!  I'm good now, Big thanks for quick answers !

Answer (score 0):

```
text <- c("01/08/2015 New Features.mp4",
          "01/08/2015 Add percent total.mp4",
          "01/08/2015 Fix length.mp4")
data <- tempfile()
writeLines(text, data)
lines <- readLines(data)
date <- substr(lines, 1, 11)
text <- substr(lines, 12, nchar(lines))
parsed <- data.frame(date = date, text = text)
```